# For Unity, how do I serialize a Json string file path and load it into a ScriptableObject asset like sprites?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

```
 //Json--------------------------
[
  {
    "name": "Generic Ability",
    "icon": "Assets/Database/Images/default.png"
  },
  {
    "name": "Another Ability",
    "icon": "Assets/Database/Images/another.png"
  }
]

//Ability--------------------------
[System.Serializable]
public class Ability
{
    public string abilityName;
    public Sprite icon;
}

//AbilityDatabase--------------------------
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "AbilityDatabase", menuName = "Ability Database", order = 2)]
public class AbilityDatabase : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<Ability> abilities;
}
```

- Current situation: I have a Json with a key/value that has a file
  path to an asset.
- Goal: I want to turn this Json into a C# ScriptableObject that loads
  the sprite from the file path instead of staying as a file path
  string.

I am having trouble with the Json to ScriptableObject asset portion script wise. I have tried using [Unity's Json.net](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.0/manual/index.html) and I have also tried using [Odin's Serializer](https://odininspector.com/documentation/sirenix.serialization.jsontextreader).

For the first one, I was able to make Unity's Json.net to mostly work but I don't think JsonConvert.DeserializeObject works with asset and with the second one, I think the Json has to be in a very specific format. Does anyone have an example with converting a Json into a ScriptableObject that loads an asset references via a string file path? I do not have any preferences framework wise.

Comment: you can't directly deserialize a `Sprite` this way ... the assets folder isn't accessible like this in a built application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct convertion from a string to an Asset, this is not how serialization works. It can convert a text file to data in a direct way, but an Asset is not its path but the data within it that would be a lot of values.

So in order to convert the JSON to your Scriptable Objects there is an intermediate step involved.

First I would suggest to install the [Newtonsoft JSON package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html). Unitys serializer is just bad, it won't serialize Arrays directly.

Open the Package manager, hit the + sign and then "Add package by name...". insert "com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json" and click add.

Maybe you have to restart the Editor, then in your serialization code change the Unity JSONUtility to JSONConverter and add

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

I added a deserialization class **AbilityJson**. This is only used to convert the JSON to an object and then we convert the asset path to an AssetLink using [AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html).

Often such workarounds are required, if this is just a one time use case then you can simply remove the additional code afterwards.

Remember, Serialization (especially JSON) is not dependend on the target framework, you can not simply convert a path to an asset, you have to define what to do with that path.

Also if you want to serialize a Sprite keep in mind that that would store the sprite data (every pixel) in a JSON file, you do not want to do that but instead find the path of the file and store that.

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class SerializeTets : MonoBehaviour
{
    [TextArea]
    public string importJson = @"
    [
      {
        ""name"": ""Generic Ability"",
        ""icon"": ""Assets/Database/Images/default.png""
      },
      {
        ""name"": ""Another Ability"",
        ""icon"": ""Assets/Database/Images/another.png""
      }
    ]";

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Ability
    {
        public string abilityName;
        public Sprite icon;
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public struct AbilityJson
    {
        public string name;
        public string icon;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AbilityJson[]>(importJson);

        abilities = new Ability[deserialized.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < deserialized.Length; i++)
        {
            var d = deserialized[i];
            var spriteAsset = (Sprite)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(d.icon);
            if (spriteAsset == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Sprite at path {d.icon} could not be found.");
            }
            abilities[i] = new Ability()
            {
                abilityName = d.name,
                icon = spriteAsset
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was marked as the solution but note: This will only work within the UnityEditor itself! `AssetDatabase` belongs to the `UnityEditor` namespace which is stripped off and not available in a built application! In a build there is no direct access to assets like that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in several ways, however, it sounds like a very weird solution. It will easily lead to huge JSON files that will take an eternity to load and parse.

The most common way is to use the combination of two elements:

- Some kind of resource management system (you can take Addressables or implement something that fits your needs better if you have time and resources)
- Configuration

In this case, you do not need to store sprites in your config. It can be any key, that your resource management system can process and provide the needed asset in exchange.

Answer (score 1):

you can use only `c# primitive data types` such as int, string, bool, etc. **And** for assets such as sprite, GameObject, etc you can actually place them inside Resource folder and when you want to access them just use string location to call them and get reference using.
`var object = Resources.Load<GameObject>(<PATH>)`
`var sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(<PATH>)`
keep in mind you can call any asset from folder name **Resources** and yes you can have multiple **Resources** folder in different directory but their assets name should be unique.

To use **PATH** eg. asset is located in `Assets/Resources/mySprite1.png`
you can use `Resources.Load<Sprite>("mySprite1")` do not include asset extension.

example using folder.

asset is located in `Assets/Resources/PlayerAssets/PlayerSkin1.png`
 use `Resources.Load<Sprite>("PlayerAssets/PlayerSkin1");`